# Конверт голова из микрофона в звук через кости

Tags: аудио, звукозапись

Не секрет, что звук пропускаемый через кости (когда мы говорим) отличается от того, что мы слышим. Но допустим, нам интересно представить как будет выглядеть звук, издаваемый другим говорящим. То есть как слышит звук через кости он. 
Есть ли решение как конвертировать звук записанный на микрофон в то, что слышит сам говорящий (слышит себя)

Comment: Плюс 1 за голову из микрофона.

Comment: Плюс 1 за "как будет выглядеть звук"

Comment: Мастерство заголовка

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbyUn.png

Answer (score 0):

Уже есть. [Наушники с костной проводимостью](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=SqIFXtDgEPaWk74PjbaN-Aw&q=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E&oq=%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.356806.356806..357388...0.1..0.51.51.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.......0i71.0yTr6RMNI1U&ved=0ahUKEwjQree8l9XmAhV2y8QBHQ1bA88Q4dUDCAs&uact=5).